# Checking and ensuring that 95% confidence intervals and p-value calculations use the same method in the final fit package in R

Tags: logistic-regression, confidence-interval, p-value

I have a missing data variable, "Age_Years", and I have run a logistic regression to see which variables, if any, are associated with having missing "Age_Years" values.

I have used the final fit package in R. The output is posted below.

```
                       Dependent: Age_Years_NA                                    No        Yes           OR (univariable)                OR (multivariable)
                                       Village                 Beng-Gaty  100 (94.3)    6 (5.7)                          -                                 -
                                                                  Ohchra  147 (96.7)    5 (3.3)  0.57 (0.16-1.93, p=0.359)         0.01 (0.00-0.18, p=0.003)
                                                                 Ohtrone   96 (93.2)    7 (6.8)  1.22 (0.39-3.90, p=0.734)        1.96 (0.15-29.39, p=0.608)
                                                                 Sraelvy  150 (97.4)    4 (2.6)  0.44 (0.11-1.59, p=0.218)         0.12 (0.01-1.72, p=0.122)
                 Persons_living_in_house_count                 Mean (SD)   5.1 (1.8)  5.1 (1.3)  0.99 (0.77-1.27, p=0.944)         0.56 (0.27-1.12, p=0.104)
                       HH_head_attended_school                        No  225 (97.0)    7 (3.0)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  267 (94.7)   15 (5.3)  1.81 (0.75-4.80, p=0.205)        1.80 (0.34-12.51, p=0.510)
                             P_falciparum_qPCR                        No  434 (95.4)   21 (4.6)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes   59 (98.3)    1 (1.7)  0.35 (0.02-1.72, p=0.310)         0.60 (0.02-6.56, p=0.713)
                                  P_vivax_qPCR                        No  378 (95.7)   17 (4.3)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  115 (95.8)    5 (4.2)  0.97 (0.31-2.50, p=0.948)         1.14 (0.23-5.29, p=0.870)
                          Fever_in_last_2_days                        No  484 (95.8)   21 (4.2)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes    8 (88.9)   1 (11.1) 2.88 (0.15-16.78, p=0.329) 810.74 (1.74-6448770.99, p=0.082)
                                       Ill_now                        No  471 (95.7)   21 (4.3)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes   22 (95.7)    1 (4.3)  1.02 (0.06-5.24, p=0.985)         0.03 (0.00-3.92, p=0.342)
           Treatment_for_illness_in_last_month                        No  296 (96.4)   11 (3.6)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  197 (95.2)   10 (4.8)  1.37 (0.56-3.30, p=0.485)         1.67 (0.38-8.02, p=0.504)
          Antimalarial_treatment_last_2_months                        No  421 (95.5)   20 (4.5)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes   71 (97.3)    2 (2.7)  0.59 (0.09-2.09, p=0.487)         0.76 (0.06-5.93, p=0.811)
               Slept_elsewhere_in_last_4_weeks                        No  399 (95.9)   17 (4.1)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes   94 (94.9)    5 (5.1)  1.25 (0.40-3.25, p=0.670)        2.38 (0.47-11.12, p=0.270)
                       Worked_in_last_2_months                        No   38 (88.4)   5 (11.6)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  455 (96.4)   17 (3.6)  0.28 (0.11-0.90, p=0.019)         0.03 (0.00-0.25, p=0.003)
                             Work_Place_Cashew                        No  281 (96.2)   11 (3.8)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  212 (95.1)   11 (4.9)  1.33 (0.56-3.15, p=0.518)        5.89 (1.12-44.85, p=0.055)
                            Work_Place_Cassava                        No  366 (96.1)   15 (3.9)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  127 (94.8)    7 (5.2)  1.34 (0.50-3.27, p=0.528)      15.26 (2.62-118.47, p=0.004)
                      Work_Place_Nearby_Forest                        No  468 (95.9)   20 (4.1)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes   25 (92.6)    2 (7.4)  1.87 (0.29-6.92, p=0.415)        4.16 (0.19-69.90, p=0.325)
                         Work_Place_Rice_Field                        No  424 (95.5)   20 (4.5)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes   69 (97.2)    2 (2.8)  0.61 (0.10-2.17, p=0.518)        2.21 (0.22-17.36, p=0.463)
                                  Bednet_count                 Mean (SD)   2.8 (1.3)  3.8 (1.7)  1.55 (1.18-2.04, p=0.002)         1.76 (0.55-4.76, p=0.276)
                            Bednets_used_count                 Mean (SD)   2.5 (1.2)  3.0 (1.4)  1.40 (1.00-1.94, p=0.049)         0.51 (0.12-2.09, p=0.334)
                                 Bednet_source  Hospital / health center  306 (95.3)   15 (4.7)                          -                                 -
                                                      Purchased in store  186 (96.4)    7 (3.6)  0.77 (0.29-1.86, p=0.571)       9.07 (0.19-586.18, p=0.268)
                                                       Relative / friend     0 (NaN)    0 (NaN)                          -                                 -
                          Treated_bednet_count                 Mean (SD)   1.6 (1.6)  2.4 (2.0)  1.29 (1.01-1.66, p=0.042)        6.06 (1.05-50.84, p=0.062)
              Time_owned_personal_bednet_Years                 Mean (SD)   2.0 (1.0)  1.6 (1.2)  0.74 (0.48-1.11, p=0.152)         0.45 (0.17-0.98, p=0.066)
                           Hammocks_used_count                 Mean (SD)   0.5 (0.6)  0.6 (1.0)  1.38 (0.73-2.44, p=0.292)         0.09 (0.00-2.53, p=0.203)
                         Treated_hammock_count                         0  333 (95.4)   16 (4.6)                          -                                 -
                                                                       1 126 (100.0)    0 (0.0)                          -                                 -
                                                                       2   27 (84.4)   5 (15.6)                          -                                 -
                     Sprayed_in_past_12_months                        No  350 (96.4)   13 (3.6)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  138 (93.9)    9 (6.1)  1.76 (0.71-4.16, p=0.206)        2.71 (0.28-33.32, p=0.397)
 Received_malaria_information_in_past_3_months                        No  259 (95.2)   13 (4.8)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  233 (96.3)    9 (3.7)  0.77 (0.31-1.82, p=0.554)        1.66 (0.24-13.34, p=0.610)
          Slept_indoors_or_outdoors_last_night                   Indoors  487 (96.1)   20 (3.9)                          -                                 -
                                                                Outdoors    6 (75.0)   2 (25.0) 8.12 (1.14-37.87, p=0.014)       5.47 (0.30-101.32, p=0.229)
                                 Roof_material           Corrugated iron  427 (95.5)   20 (4.5)                          -                                 -
                                                                   Tiles   66 (97.1)    2 (2.9)  0.65 (0.10-2.29, p=0.563)        1.76 (0.09-38.22, p=0.706)
                               Window_material                No windows  182 (97.3)    5 (2.7)                          -                                 -
                                                    Windows not screened  311 (94.8)   17 (5.2)  1.99 (0.77-6.13, p=0.183)         0.98 (0.17-6.20, p=0.981)
                                Elevated_house                        No   77 (96.2)    3 (3.8)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  416 (95.6)   19 (4.4)  1.17 (0.39-5.07, p=0.802)     37.04 (1.70-5926.87, p=0.076)
                               Toilet_facility                        No  402 (95.9)   17 (4.1)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes   86 (94.5)    5 (5.5)  1.37 (0.44-3.58, p=0.542)        4.51 (0.30-91.53, p=0.285)
                          Time_to_water_source       Less than 5 minutes  266 (94.0)   17 (6.0)                          -                                 -
                                                Between 5 and 10 minutes  171 (97.7)    4 (2.3)  0.37 (0.10-1.01, p=0.075)         0.82 (0.09-7.67, p=0.853)
                                               Between 10 and 30 minutes   55 (98.2)    1 (1.8)  0.28 (0.02-1.43, p=0.227)         0.51 (0.02-7.55, p=0.644)
                                     Cat_count                         0  459 (96.2)   18 (3.8)                          -                                 -
                                                                       1  21 (100.0)    0 (0.0)                          -                                 -
                                                                       2    7 (63.6)   4 (36.4)                          -                                 -
                                                                       3   6 (100.0)    0 (0.0)                          -                                 -
                                  Cattle_count                 Mean (SD)   1.1 (2.0)  0.6 (1.3)  0.85 (0.58-1.10, p=0.314)         0.42 (0.11-0.98, p=0.121)
                                 Chicken_count                 Mean (SD)   7.6 (7.5)  6.2 (4.2)  0.97 (0.90-1.03, p=0.379)         0.96 (0.83-1.07, p=0.479)
                                     Pig_count                 Mean (SD)   2.4 (2.4)  2.4 (2.5)  0.99 (0.81-1.16, p=0.904)         1.15 (0.76-1.75, p=0.515)
                          Axillary_temperature                 Mean (SD)  37.0 (0.4) 37.0 (0.5)  1.27 (0.45-3.48, p=0.649)         0.85 (0.14-5.44, p=0.862)
                            Bednet_sufficiency                        No  169 (97.1)    5 (2.9)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  319 (94.9)   17 (5.1)  1.80 (0.70-5.56, p=0.256)        1.85 (0.07-61.78, p=0.718)
                    Treated_bednet_sufficiency                        No  310 (96.3)   12 (3.7)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  182 (94.8)   10 (5.2)  1.42 (0.59-3.36, p=0.424)         0.04 (0.00-2.64, p=0.183)
                            Infected_Household                        No  164 (95.9)    7 (4.1)                          -                                 -
                                                                     Yes  329 (95.6)   15 (4.4)  1.07 (0.44-2.84, p=0.888)       8.78 (1.14-109.88, p=0.057)
                                          <NA>                      <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  1.90 (1.02-3.15, p=0.020)         2.49 (0.70-9.91, p=0.164)
                                          <NA>                      <NA>        <NA>       <NA>  1.31 (0.64-2.45, p=0.431)       9.50 (0.40-530.02, p=0.211)
```

My question/curiosity is, why do I have a p-value (in the multivariable column) that is >0.05 when the 95% confidence interval for the odds ratio does NOT include 1? There are numerous examples in the output, including for "Workplace_Cassava", "Treated_bednet_count", "Time_owned_personal_bednet_Years", "Elevated_house", and "Infected_household".

I notice that for most of the "dubious" variables, the 95% confidence interval is very wide, but not for all (Time owned personal bednet, for example). Besides, I would have thought it would not have mattered how wide the confidence interval was; I would have thought (just based on the underlying mathematics of statistics) that if the 95% confidence interval does not include 1, then the p-value should be <0.05, and vice-versa, but that is not the case.

I am assuming that it might be because the methods used to calculate the 95% CIs and the p-values are not the same, but I have no idea how to check this or standardise this.

How can I check the methods and standardise them?